# regular expression for commenting out all print statements in a file if followed by a particular string

Tags: php, regex, string, perl, printing

I have a file that looks similar to this:

```
<?php
    print "hello world" . "<br/>";
    print "foobar" . "<br/>";
    ...
    // Process parameter
    if ($var) {
        print $var . "<br/>";
    }
    ...
    print "foo" . "<br/>";
    ...
    print "bar" . "<br/>";
    ...
>?
```

I need a regular expression that comments out all the print statements, IF said statements appear after the `Process parameter` comment.

I'm using perl to process the file above, by the way.

I've come up the following regex but it's not working:

```
~(?s)(// Process parameter.*?)print(.*?\?\>)~$1//print$3~gi
```

Do I need to use a regex conditional?  I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe your issue is you are not accounting for multi-line matches. Try adding \n and/or \r to your expression somewhere. I'm not sure where though, maybe like this: `~(?s)(// Process parameter.*?+\n\r)print(.*?\?\>)~$1//print$3~gi`

Comment: If it's a perl regex, you'll need a trailing `m` to make it work over multi-lines.

Comment: I believe the `(?s)` treats the string as single line.  Shouldn't that account for multi-line matching?

Comment: @user717236 - I'm a little rusty with perl regexps (and my google fu is weak today); do you have a link for that? I have seen that a /s modifier will treat the string as a single line. I've not seen anything that has the modifier at the start of the regex, though.

Comment: If you go to this link (http://affy.blogspot.com/p5be/ch10.htm) and scroll to the extended patterns (Table 10.8), you'll see it talks about how you can put modifiers at the beginning rather than the end of the delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the suggestions.  I did figure it out, though.

```
~(?s)(?<=// Process parameter.*?)(print.*?)~//$1~gi
```

I'm using a look-behind assertion with the s option to treat the string as a single line.  It only matches print if followed by the contents of the look-behind assertion.